# Decimate mod breaks apart model

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I just started using blender and don't really know my way around everything just yet.
I wanted to use the decimate modifier on my model. It worked fine, apart from highlighting a few areas. I thought it would go away if I applied the modifier, but it then deletes the highlighted part of the model as soon as I do that (or maybe makes it invisible? I can't tell).
What did I do wrong, and how do I reverse it?

Thanks in advance[image]
[image]

Comment: use Ctrl+Z to undo or *File > Revert* to recover the last saved version or *File > Recover > Auto Save* to restore the autosaved file.

Comment: Have you checked the normals of the mesh? The mesh should not vanish if you apply the *Decimate* modifier. It's not invisible but broken :(

Comment: Thank you @Blunder! I will try to check everything again to see where my mistake was, but at least I was able to recover an autosave. :)